# How do you include a poster in an academic resume?

Tags: conference, cv, poster

I'm a chemistry major and I've done a few poster presentations and an oral presentation. I have to put together an academic resume for a class. I was told to include mt presentations.

First off, are these things worthwhile to include or is it like putting in that participation ribbon you earned in gym class in 5th grade?

If it's worthwhile to list these things, how do I do so? Do I separate the oral presentation from the posters? Do I include the name of the conference it was presented at?

Comment: Are you in a field (Eg CS), where a poster presentation (and an oral presentation) are accepted to a conference based on the submission of a peer reviewed paper detailing the completed work?

Comment: A good solution is to look at several other people's CVs in your field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In academia, one lists things related to accomplishments and dissemination of research in the CV.  This typically includes things like papers or preprints, software, as well as presentations one gives.  In particular, your list of presentations gives one piece of information into how active you are in your research community.  So yes, assuming your poster presentations are academic/research related, it's appropriate to put them in your CV, though in-class presentations are typically not included.

General comments:  a CV is different than a resume so there's a lot of flexibility in what you include and how you format it.  Still, there are some dos and don'ts.  You can find loads of example CVs online, but it might be most helpful for you to look at sample CVs of young researchers (students, postdocs) in your field for some models.

Specific comments: there are different ways you can organize your presentations, but my suggestion is make a section titled presentations, and within that two subsections, one for oral presentations or "talks" and one for poster presentations.  Then for each presentation, list the title, venue including conference name and date.  E.g.

- From Cervantes to Swift, *33rd AEIOU Conference*, University of Lillipilut, Mildendo, Lilliput, April 1, 1726.

Comment: Note: I am assuming you're not in a situation where presentations have "multiple authors"---if you are, list your "coauthors" as well, in a similar format to other CVs you find in your field.

Comment: Just wanted to add that everything on the CV should be findable by the person reading it. So, the conference proceedings where the poster (at least abstract) is published should be provided. Since this can lead to formatting ugliness on paper, you should include a DOI on the CV. If the journal doesn't provide one, you can publish the material in [Zenodo](http://www.zenodo.org) or [Figshare](http://www.figshare.org)