# Include Poster Paper in Academic CV

Tags: conference, cv, poster

I want to know how much does it matter to include poster paper list in an academic CV. I see some researchers and professors put poster list in their CV, however, it is not widely used. Note that, I am talking about the poster papers that are often accepted as a separate track e.g., `Demo/Poster Track` in top-tier computer science, electronics and communication engineering-based conferences.

(I am aware that some flagship conferences put some paper as poster presentation instead of oral presentation due to the huge number of accepted papers, however, all of them are included in the conference proceedings irrespective of oral or poster presentation.)

Here is some relevant discussion:

[How do you include a poster in an academic resume?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65473/how-do-you-include-a-poster-in-an-academic-resume)

[Poster author added me as coauthor after abstract was submitted. Can I include it on CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/poster-author-added-me-as-coauthor-after-abstract-was-submitted-can-i-include-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is included in the conference proceedings then **sure**, include it. It is important to make it clear that it is not a full paper so people have a separate section for listing things like posters or workshop papers.

But how much does it matter? For impressing a hiring committee, not much. It usually isn't very prestigious to present a poster and the acceptance rate is often very high

It is still your work though and was published, so I would list it mostly for completeness.

---

If it isn't included in the proceedings, then I probably wouldn't include it. The advice I have been told is that it will reduce the signal-to-noise ratio of my CV. Although, I have seen some of my friends in the humanities include such things so it might depend on your field.

Comment: Got it. How about a poster paper in top-tier IEEE conference compared to low grade conference (even supported by IEEE)? Still don't it have any credit? Yes, I agree that we can put in separate list in CV.

Comment: @Mithun From my experience, posters are weighted very low, regardless of the venue. But if your publication list is short then I do think it could be beneficial for applying to PhD programs or scholarships.